# The profile image obtained of the taggable friends API response, it has expiry time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am creating an app that should get the list of facebook friends. After selecting a friend , the image of it should be displayed in the app for undetermined time. Does anyone know if the profile image coming through the " taggable_friends " has expiration time?

Comment: Yes it does. Taggable_friends will just be approved for tagging. Nothing else

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for the trouble!!

Comment: In general, all URLs pointing to content on Facebook’s CDNs should be considered “transient” – you should not store them for long-time use.

Comment: ok! Thanks! @CBroe